# Visualforce Page Not in Options When Overriding Standard Leads Tab

Tags: apex, visualforce, tab

I have created a visualforce page that displays all leads. Problem is, the page I created is not on the options when overriding standard `Lead` tab.

**Apex Class**

```
public class MyLeadClass {

    private ApexPages.StandardController c;
    public List<Lead> leadQry {get;set;}

    public MyLeadClass(ApexPages.StandardController con) {
        c = con; 
    } 

    public List<Lead> getMyLeads() {

        List<Lead> leadQry = new List<Lead>();
        leadQry = [SELECT Id, Name, Title, Email FROM Lead];   
        return leadQry;

    }

}
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="MyLeadClass" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">

    <apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!MyLeads}" var="ml">

                <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!ml.Name}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Title" value="{!ml.Title}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Email" value="{!ml.Email}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>  

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Leads Tab, or Leads List View? As far as I can tell, you can specify any page you want for a Home Tab.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override a Tab with a VF page that uses a Standard Controller. You can however use the Standard List Controller, a Custom Controller, or no Controller.

More info here on overriding tabs with Standard List Controller: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_overrides.htm

Here's example with a custom controller:

```
<apex:page controller="MyLeadClass" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!MyLeads}" var="ml">
            <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!ml.Name}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Title" value="{!ml.Title}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Email" value="{!ml.Email}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

And it is now selectable in the dropdown:
[image]